# How can i convert date("j/n/y") to epoch

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have some data that makes use of `date("j/n/y")` format i.e date for today is `23/1/15`

I have tried

```
echo strtotime($today);
```

but this does not give me the timestamp i want.How would i convert a date in `date("j/n/y")` format to epoch?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to read the date format and then use [`DateTime::getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) to format it as a timestamp.

```
$date  = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/y', '23/1/15');
$epoch = $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `mktime()` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, but it requires breaking the date apart which is a bit more work.

Comment: Ok, I was in the middle of posting an answer using `mktime` when I second-guessed myself lol

Comment: @TimLewis It doesn't hurt to show an alternative approach. I say post it.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks. Maybe i add,this on how to get the date back from epoch `echo date('j/n/y', $epoch);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `mktime` function in PHP. It goes a little like this:

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

Where, in order, the arguments are: hour, minute, second, month, day, year. So, in your case:

```
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 23, 2015); 
// Would return the timestamp for Jan. 23rd, 2015 at 12:00:00 am (I think)
```

If you're looking for a dynamic *right now* timestamp, you may use `date()` in each of the arguments of mktime. For example:

```
$rightnow = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
// Would return the timestamp for Jan. 23rd, 2015 at 10:57:25 am.
```

But, as John Conde says, it requires you break apart the date before you can use it, so it may not be as efficient.

Hope that helps!

Comment: First parameter of `mktime()` function is hour, not seconds. If you are looking for now timestamp, you don't need to set every parameter, because current is already set, see default function parameters in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). Note: `As of PHP 5.1, when called with no arguments, mktime() throws an E_STRICT notice: use the time() function instead.`

Comment: No, default is `H,i,s,n,j,Y` :)

Comment: Yes, and `H` meaning 24-hour format, not `h` which is 12-hour format. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) what this format characters mean.

Comment: Bah, right right... Had that in my answer, wrote hastily in my comment lol

Answer (score 0):

Just to have another approach this one would be good for 85 more years.

```
$date = date('j/n/y', time());

list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date);

$date = "20" . $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;

echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
```